# Entity Framework Core Order By

Tags: database, entity-framework-core, blazor

I want to retrieve data from a database from a specific column sorted by the column, plus distinct. The data is also fetched distinctly, but not sorted. My query looks like this:

```
 return context.TableName.OrderBy(l => l.ColumnName).Select(p => p.ColumnName)
            .Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Distinct itself discards ordering. It is because of realisation and it depends on Database. So do ordering after `Distinct`.

```cs
return context.TableName
   .Select(p => p.ColumnName)
   .Distinct()
   .OrderBy(l => l)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: But I have to do the order by before the select or not, otherwise I can't sort it by a table or not ? :)

Comment: You have to do OrderBy only after Distinct.